# My custom middleware exception doesnt work in my .NET Core Web Api application

Tags: exception, .net-core

This is my custom middleware class for exception. I want to handle global exceptions.

```
public class CustomExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CustomExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<CustomExceptionMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, e);

        }            
    }
    private  Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        if(exception is KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            _logger.LogInformation("Exception happend. Exception type: " + exception.GetType().ToString(), new object[0]);
        }
        else if (exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            _logger.LogInformation("Exception happend. Exception type: " + exception.GetType().ToString(), new object[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            _logger.LogInformation("Exception happend. Bad request ", new object[0]);
        }
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = exception.Message });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) code;
        //context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class CustomExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

I add in my Startup.cs

```
app.UseCustomExceptionMiddleware();
```

I don't get logging information that I'm trying to log, and it doesn't throw any exception. What am I missing? Should I throw an exception in a controller class?

Comment: What output did you configure for your Ilogger instance? How did you configure it?

Comment: Sorry for digging this up a year later - can't say exactly what your problem was, but for future reference [this site](http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) has a good rundown of the process